# Filter JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, filter

How can I filter a Google Spreadsheet JSON (like this one: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/18wLFkAE92tx8JL2WeKFNv2dosT0qSHoHYqdhqS7xbQQ/1/public/values?alt=json), so all I get to work with is the json-entry, where there is a `"title":{"type":"text","$t":"test1"}` aka «*where title = test1*».

All I want to get out the *full JSON* is the **one entry**, where there is a child with title = test1 … from `id` to `gsx$articletitle` or what ever is in the same entry. To display only this one entry (filtered via *title*) on a website.

```
"id": {
    "$t": "FULLURL"
},
… blablabla …
"title": {
    "type": "text",
    "$t": "test1"
},
… blablabla …
"gsx$articletitle": {
    "$t": "Viva la Grischa"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the JSON is parsed into a variable:

```
var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(THE_STRING_FROM_GOOGLE).feed.entry;
```

you can filter it like so:

```
arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.filter(function(o){
  return o.title.$t == "test1";
});
```

You can then get the values like so (a few examples):

```
var myFoundObject = arrayOfObjects[0];

console.log(myFoundObject.content.$t);
console.log(myFoundObject.content.type);
console.log(myFoundObject.category[0].scheme);
console.log(myFoundObject.category[0].term);
console.log(myFoundObject.title.$t);
console.log(myFoundObject.id.$t);
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hkkkLz4y/1/

Comment: @albuvee Updated the answer to include an example (including the fiddle link) :)